# printing a string's "canonical print-escaped form"

Tags: zsh, quoting

I'm trying to write a function, I'll call it `escape`, that will behave like this:

```
% IFS=$' \t\n\000'
% escape FOO $IFS
FOO=$' \t\n\000'
```

In other words, `escape` takes two arguments, and then, taking the first one to be a variable name, it prints out a line a zsh *source code* in which a variable of that name is assigned a `$''`-quoted, "canonically `print`-escaped" string, such that, upon evaluating this line of source code, the variable named by the the first argument will have the second argument as its value.  (I'm sure that was as clear as mud, so I'll give more examples of how `escape` is supposed to behave at the end of this post.)

Here's an incomplete implementation of the `escape` function:

```
escape () {
    local varname=$1
    local value="$2"
    print -n "$varname=\$'"
    # ???
    print "'"
}
```

The missing part (indicated by `???`) is where the contents of `$value` are "canonically `print`-escaped".  The qualifier "canonical" is necessary because there are many characters for which there are at least a couple of representations that `print` will recognize them as.  For example, `print` knows `\n` also as `\012` and as `\C-J`.  In this case, `\n` is the canonical form.  In general, the standard escape sequences `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, etc. are the canonical forms for their corresponding characters.  The standard display form of printable ASCII characters (e.g. `A`, `=`, `9`) are canonical.  For the remaining characters, if there's a choice of representation, I'd pick the octal form as the canonical one (at least up to `\177`; I'm not sure of how `$''` deals with higher codes), but this preference is not strong.

Of course, I'm not looking to see code to implement this functionality "from scratch", as it were.  Rather, I'm hoping that a utility already exists to perform this translation from bytes to a `print`-escaped text representation.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

---

Here are some more examples of `escape` in action (hypothetically):

```
% escape HELLO $( echo 'hello world' )
HELLO=$'hello world\n'
% escape SUBSEP $( perl -e 'print $;' )
SUBSEP=$'\034'
% abc=$'\141\012\142\012\143\012'
% print -n $abc
a
b
c
% escape ABC $abc
ABC=$'a\nb\nc\n'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think ing for the `q` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags), specifically the `qqqq` variant.

```
FOO=${(qqqq)IFS}
```

So you can write your function this way (using the `P` flag to expand the parameter whose name is `$2`):

```
escape () {
  print -r -- "$1=${(Pqqqq)2}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, sorry, I fail to see the relevance of your answer to my question.  As I explicitly stated, I want the output of `escape FOO $IFS` (with `$IFS` set as in my original post) to be the string `"FOO=$' \t\n\000'"`, *verbatim*, and not the string `"FOO=${(qqqq)IFS}"`, nor the string `"FOO="` followed by the string that `${(qqqq)IFS}` gets expanded to (which is not easy to reproduce in a comment but is nothing remotely like the string `"$' \t\n\000'"`).

Comment: Sorry, there's a bug in the stackexchange software that causes a space to be lost in the first appearance of the substring `"$' \t\n\000'"` in my previous comment.

Comment: @kjo I told you the main feature you would use to implement the `escape` function, I didn't think implementing the function itself was part of the difficulty. But there you go, here's an `escape` function.

Comment: No, what I was missing was the `-r` flag to `print`, without which your original answer is not useful.  Thanks.